# Маскирование email адреса Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо строку petrov@ivanov.net превратить в ***rov@**anov.net. Т.е. нужно маскировать первые три символа адреса и первые два символа после знака @.
Я смог сделать только маскирование первых трех элементов. Замаскировать элементы после @ не получается

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.{3}(.*)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
return matcher.replaceAll("***$1");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно разбить адрес на группы и сохранить их.

```
String email = "user@domain.com";

System.out.println(email.replaceFirst("^.{3}([^@]*@).{2}(.*)", "***$1**$2"));
// -> ***r@**main.com
```